# Repeating API requests until new data arrives

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm struggling with that one. 
I have old piece of data. I would like to call to API in interval of 5 seconds until I will get the new equivalent of that data. 
I'm trying to this like that(see the comments inside the code):

```
const requestTimeout = async(currentData, resolve) => {
  //that's my working call to API ;)
  const { data } = await requestGet(URL.LOTTERIES_LIST);

  // if old data is equal to new data let's try again until the backend API will finally change data to new
  if(currentData === data.newData) {
    this.setTimeout(requestTimeout(currentData, resolve), 5000);
  } else {
    resolve(data.newData);
  }
};

// this is a function which is called from another part of app, I need to return/resolve a new data from here, current Data is just old piece of data 
export function callUntilNewDataArrives(shouldCallAPI, currentData) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (shouldCallAPI) {
      requestTimeout(currentData, resolve);
    }
  });
```

As stated in comments in another part of the app I try to use callUntilNewDataArrives function simply like that:

```
callUntilNewDataArrives(shouldCallAPI, currentData)
      .then(res => console.log(res));
```

This however won't work. Thank you for any help!

Comment: if `shouldCallAPI` is `false`, then you are never resolving the promise.

Comment: What is `this.setTimeout`? Did you notice that you are passing a promise to it, not a callback?

Comment: As per the comment above, try `setTimeout(requestTimeout, 5000, currentData, resolve);` instead of the respective line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is in your objects comparison. 
The only possible reason that promise is resolved with old data is that 
`if(currentData === data.newData)` returns false every time. 
I'd check it in the debugger to be sure.